# Manga about a boy with abusive parents who is reincarnated in an isekai world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for this manga I came across one day about a boy who grows up in an abusive household. I think his father strangles him or something and after that he wakes up in another world. I think he uses a sword or something and he has trust issues.

Answer (score 3):

*Ubau Mono Ubawareru Mono* (2016)? Also known as *Those Being Stolen From, Those Who Steal; To Deprive a Deprived Person; Bereave or Bereaved*.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/99410/Ubau_Mono_Ubawareru_Mono):

> Setou Yuu is a 12-year-old boy, despite being very intelligent, he is a deprived person. Abused violently by his father and beaten by debt collectors regularly due to his father, his body filled with scars. One day, he is transported into a different world and he got what he needed to strike back at those who harm him or his loved ones.

---

Found with the Google query `isekai manga abusive father other world site:myanimelist.net/manga` which brought up [this recommendation](https://myanimelist.net/recommendations/manga/97579-99410):

> Both are set in a fantasy world. "Ubau Mono Ubawareru Mono" is a slightly more sinister manga, with **the MC having being strangled to death by his abusive father and ending up in new world**, with a slightly evil approach to others that cross him. [...]

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Yep that's the one! Thank you